# Convert object with nested unbounded size array to CSV

Tags: arrays, csv, export-to-csv

I'd like to create a CSV-based format for communicating with third parties (I know JSON would be better but it's not my choice) and I'm stuck with the way to represent nested unbounded arrays.

My object looks like this:

```
Object: {
  prop1: "some value",
  prop2: ["one", "two", "maybe more"]
}
```

As you can guess, I can't know in advance how many elements will be in the `prop2` field (different from one object to another) and I need to provide a header line in my CSV file that deals with it.

One solution that could work (but not very elegant) : iterating through my objects, finding the one with the largest `prop2` array (let's say 3 elements for the example) and writing that kind of header

```
prop1; prop2[0]; prop2[1]; prop2[2];
```

Most of my objects would have the prop2[1] field empty, which is not a problem, but I'm wondering if there is other (more elegant) solutions.

Thanks !